# Is there a way to check why I am getting an index out of range error?

Tags: python, list, csv, append

I am attempting to extract data from a csv file and plot it in a program using matplotlib in python. The csv file is 3 columns with a space between the middle two, and I am attempting to sort each column into a list, but it is telling me list index out of range on both columns.

I have tried various alterations, and tried to use a dictionary, but my ability with python isn't great because I'm not super familiar with it.

This s what I am left with from my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

plt.grid(which='major')   
plt.xlim(140,300)
plt.ylim(0,90)
plt.ylabel(r'Altitude [km]')
plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')

ALT = []
T = []

with open('atmoprofile.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for col in lines:
        T.append((col[0]))
        ALT.append((col[2]))

print(ALT)
print(T)

plt.plot(T,ALT, color = 'm' , marker = '.')
plt.savefig('FIG3.1.png',dpi=300)
```

And the error is as follows

```
 line 19, in <module>
    T.append((col[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And this is some of the csv file

```
0.0000000000000000 295.38598510303814 2.1301675254755913E-002
0.50000000000000000 293.34076715919269 1.8661556016220760E-002
1.0000000000000000 291.26698316703533 1.6456139406729336E-002
1.5000000000000000 289.15220287599828 1.4345195644685916E-002
2.0000000000000000 286.97824981214990 1.2453493432569643E-002
2.5000000000000000 284.76134910419995 1.0778799478271171E-002
3.0000000000000000 282.47997944552532 9.1857871206039686E-003
3.5000000000000000 280.14277632253931 7.8700783601433066E-003
```

Comment: Even if the data in the file is separated by a comma, the issue still persists

Comment: It is essentially 200 lines of what I just posted

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check why I am getting an index out of range error?

Yes. You can add a `print(col)` to your loop to see what it actually looks like and how many elements are in it.

Comment: Thank you, still though it is only appending one row into the first list, even though I am trying to have it select the first data value from each column

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` allows you to specify your delimiter. In your case this would just be a single space.

So line 19 of your code should be:
`lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')`

See here for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: I have tried that before but it does not fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Your code with `delimiter=' '` added to the `csv.reader` line  and with that data does not produce the error claimed.  What is still wrong, however, is the data should be converted to `float` and the x and y limits are set incorrectly to view the data provided.  I just commented them out.  Below works with the sample data shown:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

plt.grid(which='major')   
#plt.xlim(140,300)
#plt.ylim(0,90)
plt.ylabel(r'Altitude [km]')
plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')

ALT = []
T = []

with open('atmoprofile.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for col in lines:
        T.append(float(col[0]))    # convert to float
        ALT.append(float(col[2]))

print(ALT)
print(T)

plt.plot(T,ALT, color = 'm', marker = '.')
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('FIG3.1.png',dpi=300)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have tried turning it into a float, list index out of range still occurs

Comment: @jlan160 You’ve got some problem that you aren’t showing because the code above works with your exact  data posted

Comment: @jlan160 maybe it is only a particular line causing the failure. `print(col)` at the top of the for loop and report it’s value before the failure.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is that [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns a list of strings :

> `csv.reader`(*csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams*):
> **Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.** No automatic data type conversion is performed unless the QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified (in which case unquoted fields are transformed into floats).
>
> *Source* : [[python.docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents)]

With a [`float`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#float) cast, I would do it this way :

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.grid(which='major')   
plt.ylabel(r'Altitude [km]')
plt.xlabel('Temperature [K]')

with open('atmoprofile.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    T, ALT = zip(*[(float(row[0]), float(row[2])) for row in reader])

plt.plot(T, ALT, color='m', marker='.')
# plt.savefig('FIG3.1.png', dpi=300) # uncomment this line to make a fig/png
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason it still tells me list index out of range